# Does speed matter while one steel part is pressed into another?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, steel

If one press some steel part into steel hole to get unsplittable assembly, does this operation speed matter? Is it better to hit by hammer, or to slowly jam with vice? Does it relate to steel type (e.g. soft or hardened)?

Comment: Based on your comment about avoiding thermal effects, check out how Joule measured energy based on machining cannon barrels.

Comment: @SolarMike I suggest it was Rumford. Anyway I did not understood yet, do thermal effects determine optimal press speed, or not. It was just a hypothesis.

Comment: Any idea why we measure in Joules instead of Rumfords?

Comment: @SolarMike AFAIK Joule did his measurements with water. He found numerical thermomechanical relation, while Rumford just discovered this phenomena.

Comment: Joule based his experiments on Rumford's and sorted the theory which Rumford did not ...

Comment: @SolarMike OK. Thus I can say: higher speed leads to higher deformation (material heats, expands, softens, deforms). If this is not our goal for some reason, we should prefer low speed to keep dimensions stable and get tighter fit.

Comment: I don't follow the discussion in the comments, it's typical here to have completely unnecessary discussions ... The strain rate determines the properties of material, i don't know what exactly you want, but i guess the 'the effect of strain rate'  is the correct start point.